# Find record only by value Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

i don't know the key name, can i get record only by value?
Example:

```
db.people.insertMany([
   { id: "1", city: a, zipCode : 1111},
   { id: "2", qty: b, zipCode : 2222},
   { id: "3", qty: c, zipCode : 333},
   { id: "4", qty: e,  zipCode : 1111},
   { id: "5", qty: d,  zipCode : 4444},
]); 

db.people.find( _ : 111)]

     { id: "1", city: a, zipCode : 1111},
     { id: "4", qty: e,  zipCode : 1111},
```

where "_" represent some generic key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely value `111` will not return documents with value `1111`. Anyway, you could use this one:

```
db.people.aggregate([
   { $set: { _: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } } },
   { $match: { "_.v": 1111 } },
   { $unset: "_" }
])
```

But it works only on top-level elements. Nested documents are not covered by this.